# Azure Blob Storage C#: Disposing stream after an async upload method call

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, upload, stream

I'm having difficulties finding the correct way of calling dispose to a stream after an async upload method call.

Below you'll see the method I use to upload a file to Azure in an async way, and I created an AsyncCallback because I need to write to a log all success and fail operations.

I've written the method in an async way trying to achieve a little bit more of performance (this is an API that receives a json with dozens -maybe hundreads- of images urls to be uploaded to Azure).

The method works just fine, but the fact is I'm not sure about how/where to dispose the stream object marked in bold. I have commented the using because "using" it I have unexpected results, presumably from the stream being disposed before the upload takes place, I guess.

As extra-info, the main method -which calls upload- has three nested foreach that iterates over a json and *TmpModelsJsonIterationInfo* is a class that holds the current element being iterated for the three foreach, because I need them mainly for the log.

In main method, I'm creating the main (original) stream from the url given in json and passing it to upload method (as a TmpModelsJsonIterationInfo property) where the image is resized according to an array of sizes (resolutions) so a new stream is created for each size, and this is the stream I'm not sure where to close/dispose.

Maybe I can add a new property to *TmpModelsJsonIterationInfo* to hold the stream and dispose it in *OnUploadCompleted* the same way as I'm doing with the original stream?

```
private void UploadFile(TmpModelsJsonIterationInfo tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, (int Width, int Height)> size in VersionDefinitions.AssetResolutions)
                {
                    Stream **stream** = resizeImage(tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOriginalStreamFile, size);
                    stream.Position = 0;

                    //using (Stream stream = resizeImage(tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOriginalStreamFile, size)) {
                    //stream.Position = 0;
                    string sizeName = size.Key;
                    string azureFile = sizeName + "/" + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentAssetId;

                    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = Azure.GetBlockBlobReference(_container, azureFile);
                    blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentContentType;

                    tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentBlockBlob = blockBlob;
                    tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentSize = sizeName;

                    AsyncCallback UploadCompleted = new AsyncCallback(OnUploadCompleted);
                    blockBlob.BeginUploadFromStream(stream, UploadCompleted, tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo);
                    //}
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logMessage("KO - Uploading assetId: " + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentAssetId + ": " + e.Message, Level.Error);
            }
        }

        private void OnUploadCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            TmpModelsJsonIterationInfo tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo = (TmpModelsJsonIterationInfo)result.AsyncState;
            tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.UploadCounter++;
            try
            {
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentBlockBlob;
                blockBlob.SetMetadata();
                blockBlob.EndUploadFromStream(result);

                //log OK
                if (blockBlob.Properties.Length != -1)
                {
                    tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOrderedAsset["AssetId"] = tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentAssetId;
                    tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOrderedAsset["State"] = true;
                    string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
                    logMessage(
                        "Upload OK" + newLine +
                        "ModelVencaID: " + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentModelId + newLine +
                        "ColorVencaID: " + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentColorId + newLine +
                        "AssetId: " + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentAssetId + newLine +
                        "Source Url: " + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentUrl + newLine +
                        "Target Url: " + DataBridgeSettings.Instance.AzureImagesDomainURL +
                            "/images/" + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentSize + "/" + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentAssetId + newLine +
                        "---------", Level.Info);
                } else {
                    tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOrderedAsset["AssetId"] = 0;
                    tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOrderedAsset["State"] = false;
                }

                if (tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.UploadCounter == _numberOfSizes) {
                    tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOriginalStreamFile.Close();
                    tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOriginalStreamFile.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOrderedAsset["AssetId"] = 0;
                tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentOrderedAsset["State"] = false;
                logMessage("KO - Uploading assetId: " + tmpModelsJsonIterationInfo.CurrentAssetId + ": " + e.Message, Level.Error);
            }
        }
```